# how to read, with google apps script, the heading reference in a google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Question: how to read the heading reference (of the form #heading=h.12345) in a google docs doc?

Background: Would like to use cross-references within doc. Example.

```
1.1 Chapter 1 (i.e. paragraph has heading DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1)

Sample text. For more, see chapter 1.2.

1.2 Chapter 2

Sample text. For more, see chapter 1.1.
```

Now, google docs can do cross-references (insert link), but are "normal" links and do not carry the chapter number.

Thus, approach would be to:
 - insert links for cross-references

- with apps script, build index of heading references and chapter numbers
- also with apps script, update see chapter texts based on their link

I looked at getLinkUrl without success:

```
var links = [];
var ps = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getParagraphs();
for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
  var h = ps[i].getHeading();
  if( h == DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1 ) {
    var t = ps[i].editAsText();
    var u = t.getLinkUrl();
  }
}
```

Is it possible to read the heading reference at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to read the heading reference at all?

Absolutely, at least from the Table of Contents. Those references are in the `attributes` of the TOC entries. You can see an example, with a script, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344552/1677912).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code (modified slightly) to detect HEADING1 assuming there is only one instance. It can be adapted to detect other heading types and multiple occurrences.

```
function get_some_heading() {
  var ps = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody()
  var searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
  var searchHeading = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;
  var searchResult = null;

  while (searchResult = ps.findElement(searchType, searchResult)) {
    var par = searchResult.getElement().asParagraph();
    if (par.getHeading() == searchHeading) {
      // Found one, update Logger.log and stop.
      var h = searchResult.getElement().asText().getText();

      return h;
    }
  }

  //return null or something
}
```

Here is the enum [Paragraph Heading](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph-heading) reference and here is the [search pattern](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row) reference used above (for a slightly different use case).