# Google Appscript: Output of parsing function for a Table of Contents results in an array of objects not in the correct format. Help appreciated

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am currently trying to parse the url and text from a table of contents on a google doc and write them into a table on google sheets.

So far I have been successful in getting the text and the url using the following code modified from the top answer in this post ([How to use .findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS) to get and parse a Document's Table of Contents Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324367/how-to-use-findelementdocumentapp-elementtype-table-of-contents-to-get-and-pa/18344552#18344552?newreg=681ec60f20d549e599dcefb19340fd54))

```
function parseTOC( docId ) {
  var contents = [];
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);

  // Define the search parameters.
  var searchElement  = doc.getBody();
  var searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_OF_CONTENTS;

  // Search for TOC. Assume there's only one.
  var searchResult = searchElement.findElement(searchType);

  if (searchResult) {
    // TOC was found
    var toc = searchResult.getElement().asTableOfContents();

    // Parse all entries in TOC. The TOC contains child Paragraph elements,
    // and each of those has a child Text element. The attributes of both
    // the Paragraph and Text combine to make the TOC item functional.
    var numChildren = toc.getNumChildren();
    for (var i=0; i < numChildren; i++) {
      var itemInfo = {}
      var tocItem = toc.getChild(i).asParagraph();
      var tocItemAttrs = tocItem.getAttributes();
      var tocItemText = tocItem.getChild(0).asText();

      // Set itemInfo attributes for this TOC item, first from Paragraph
      itemInfo.text = tocItem.getText();                // Displayed text
      // ... then from child Text
      itemInfo.linkUrl= tocItemText.getLinkUrl();      // URL Link in document
      contents.push(itemInfo);
      
    }
  }

  // Return array of objects containing TOC info
  return contents;
}

function test_parseTOC() {
  var fileId = '--Doc-ID--';
  var array = parseTOC(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId() );
  Logger.log(array)
}
```

The function test_parseTOC returns the following array:

```
[{linkUrl=#heading=h.nyq88bov1u8x, text=Google}, {text=Help, linkUrl=#heading=h.9lthewlyeqjd}]
```

Although the information is correct, the "=" is giving me trouble. When working with an array of objects I would expect it to be:

```
[{linkUrl: "#heading=h.nyq88bov1u8x", text: "Google"}, {text: "Help", linkUrl: "#heading:h.9lthewlyeqjd"}]
```

What I am trying to emulate can be outlined by this post here ([Google Apps Script: how to copy array of objects to range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052890/google-apps-script-how-to-copy-array-of-objects-to-range))

If I manually change the "=" to ":" and add quotation marks then the array works fine. Is there something with the original function I can change to produce a ":" instead of a "="? Or is there a way to modify the array of objects after the fact to replace the "=" with ":"? I could easily use concat to automatically add the quotation marks, but the "=" is out of my wheelhouse.

Thank you for any input on this

Update: It actually turns out that this code was working appropriately and I was receiving an error from a different function that was using the output of this one (i.e.  I wrote `.getSheets(0)` not `.getSheets()[0]`. I will leave up the original post in case anyone needs a working example of how to extract out links from a TOC and along with the resources to write it to a google sheet

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for example, when you modify `Logger.log(array)` to `console.log(array)`, is that the result you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike, that does give the result that I was expecting. It turns out I had an error in a different part of the code and this was a red herring. Thanks for helping me out for my first day using appscript

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In your situation. the value of `array` can be used as the object. Please don't worry. And, when your issue was resolved, how about posting it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Will do on posting the answer that resolved it although I feel very silly with it. When fetching the sheet to use I wrote ```.getSheets(0)``` not ```.getSheets()[0]```. It threw up a formatting error and my mind went right to the array. Anyways, thank you for the response and I will have the solution up by EOD